# RMI Application For ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, rmi

I want to ask that when I am writing this code for my assignment. It has been worked through. After 2 hours when I am going out, the code is not working well and pops up a lot of error messages.

In this forum, I will provide the code of client, server, interface, class, and RMIregistry Java file.

**Client-Side**

```
    private void menuAncestorAdded(javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent evt) {                                   
      try{ 
        Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1", 1045);
        Interface f = (Interface)reg.lookup("cmenu");
        System.out.println("run");
        ArrayList<foodorder> list = new ArrayList<foodorder>(); 
        System.out.println("run1");
        list =  f.cmenu(); // This error when I run the code
        System.out.println("run2");
        for(foodorder r:list){
            System.out.println(r.getMenu_name());
        }
 
      }catch (Exception ex){
          ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

**Server**

```
// To view the menu for the customers
        public ArrayList <foodorder> cmenu()throws RemoteException
        {
            try{
          sql = "SELECT ItemName,Price FROM FoodOrder"
               + " WHERE Quantity >= 1";
          ResultSet a = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
          System.out.println("Execute= " + sql);
          while(a.next()){
              cart.add(new foodorder(a.getString(1),a.getDouble(2)));
          }    
          } catch (SQLException ex){
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }
         return cart;
        }
```

**Class**

```
public class foodorder {
    private double price;
    private String menu_name;

    public foodorder(String menu_name, double price) {
        this.price = price;
        this.menu_name = menu_name;
    }
}
```

**Interface**

```
public interface Interface extends Remote{
    public ArrayList <foodorder> cmenu()throws RemoteException;
  
}
```

**RMIRegister:**

```
public class Rmiregistry {
public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException{
        
    Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1045);
    reg.rebind("cmenu",new Server()); // To view the menu for the customer
    }    
}
```

**The error:**

```
run
run1
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: food.order.system.foodorder
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:193)
```

Comment: The javadoc on [NotSerializableException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/NotSerializableException.html) says "Thrown when an instance is required to have a Serializable interface". Try implementing [java.io.Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Serializable.html) on your class. Oracle also have an [RMI tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html)

Comment: You are missing a table in your SQL query.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: The problem has already solved by Scratte. @halfer

Comment: Yes, one problem has been solved, that's great. But look at your SQL query - it appears to be invalid. Are you not using a standard SQL database, like MySQL or PostgreSQL? Or does your db access library fill in the missing table information?

Comment: I don't want to show my database to the public and I delete the table information in the code before posting in this forum. Now, my codes are worked properly and already hand to my lecturer. Thank you for your help @halfer

Comment: Right, so you showed non-working code, but did not explain that you had modified this into a non-working state for the purposes of asking a question. Undoubtedly you can appreciate how this wastes the time of readers. I would normally downvote here, for the purposes of useful feedback. A good rule of thumb when showing code is "can someone paste this into their console and compile/run with no extra effort?". If they cannot, then try to repair the sample you have given until they can.

Comment: It comes as a surprise to new contributors here that **the point of Stack Overflow is to produce useful Q&A for future developers**. It is not a discussion forum, nor is it for one-on-one technical support. In other words, if you can ask your questions so they are useful for future readers (and convenient for your readers now) then you won't go far wrong.